TUS-PHP | Upload-Metadata not being passed to backend PHP
I have a vry simple question which i cannot figure out for a while.
I have simple setup of UPPY on front end and TUS-PHP on my backend on AWS EC2 free trier.
The issue is that backend upload.php does not get the custom meta information provided by uppy on upload. Meanwhile in devtools i can see the Upload-Metadata request headers/
Dev tools screenshot
This is a part of code how i send a custom data:
uppy.on('file-added', (file) => {
    
uppy.setFileMeta(file.id, {
    relativePath: 'your/relative/path', // Set your custom relative path here
    customField1: 'value1', // Set your custom field value here
    customField2: 'value2'  // Set your custom field value here
  });

........

uppy.setFileMeta(file.id, {
    relativePath: 'your/relative/path', // Set your custom relative path here
    customField1: 'value1', // Set your custom field value here
    customField2: 'value2'  // Set your custom field value here
  });

And this is headers im getting in my php (with getallheaders())
Array
(
    [Host] => 54..***.***.174
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [Content-Length] => 365387
    [Tus-Resumable] => 1.0.0
    [X-CSRF-TOKEN] => {{ csrf_token() }}
    [Upload-Offset] => 0
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/127.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
    [Content-Type] => application/offset+octet-stream
    [Accept] => */*
    [Origin] => http://54.***.***.174
    [Referer] => http://54.***.***.174/
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7
)


Can you please suggest how can I solve this issue.
Thanks
Custom metadata (Upload-Metadata) is not being passed to TUS-PHP backend php file

Why do you expect this metadata to be in the HTTP headers? It seems an odd place to put it. Does the uppy documentation say that's where it puts it? A documentation link would be helpful.

Meanwhile in devtools i can see the Upload-Metadata request headers/...can you provide a screenshot?

Hi @ADyson, thanks for reply. this is the link https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#setmetadata.  and this is screen shot https://jumpshare.com/s/A5o3qcyvij6IW4pGbxMq

Thanks, but please [edit] your question to include this information properly in your post rather than hidden down here in the comments. Stackoverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum, you need to put all the relevant info into the main question. These comments are just for brief requests for clarification, or minor notes. Thanks

And can you also show us how you're actually sending the data to the server from your JavaScript code please? We need a [mre] of the issue
